# Revit Family Rename in a project

Tags: revit-api

Is it possible to rename families in a project through the API.  We are recently updating and standardizing our family naming convention.  I'd like to build an add-in that would rename the families in existing project to the new standard names.  I haven't had any success finding an example of this online.

I’ve successfully been able to find all the family names, however, I can’t rename the family.

I’m using the C#.

Comment: Yes you can though it needs a bit of work. first you need to export all the Editable families in the project, then rename them to what you want to be, then load renamed families into the same project and finally change each elements with the old family into new one. I may be able to show some code for each bit so you get the idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the direct way with .Name property and seems to work.

```
UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
Application app = uiapp.Application;
Document doc = uidoc.Document;

foreach(ElementId id in uidoc.Selection.GetElementIds())
{
  FamilyInstance famInstance = doc.GetElement(id) as FamilyInstance;
  if (famInstance == null) continue; //skip element

  famInstance.Symbol.Name = famInstance.Symbol.Name + " - Changed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used

```
Element ff = doc2.GetElement({insert family id here});

var bar = (from x in familycollection where x.Name == ff.LookupParameter("Family Name").AsString() select x).FirstOrDefault();

exEvent.Raise()
```