# How to change Revit Family Name using Python

Tags: python, revit

I've been reading the RevitAPI docs (still learning), searching (and finding) some answers, but I can't seem to be able to change the family name in a Revit model.  I'm new to Python and have written a handful of scripts.  Looking to get off dead center on this one.

Basically, I want to rename a family called "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (PIN07)" to some other name, say "Billy's New Family Is Nice"

I'm able to get the name, but everything I try after that just fizzles.

```
Elements = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(FamilySymbol).WhereElementIsElementType()
for m in Elements:
    try:
        contains = "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (PIN07)"
        if m.FamilyName.startswith((contains)):
            print m.FamilyName
            m.FamilyName = "Some Name"
    except:
        print "I'm a reject and can't get this right."
```

I've also tried to understand how to rename a Type (Symbol) with a family and can't figure that out either.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: It gives me the name of the family that it found in the model.  What I want to do is change the name of the family it finds.  I've tried m.FamilyName = "new Name" but that doesn't change it.

Comment: Ah, so could you update the code with that attempt?

Comment: Could you also point readers to the section of the docs you are looking at that details how to reset this thing? I wonder if it would be a setter on the `m` object, rather than a property.

Comment: halter, I greatly appreciate your help!  Here's the link to the RevitAPIdocs that I was looking at.  I'm still trying to grasp everything.  https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/0f8a54e0-1382-6930-fa33-cd55054f05f8.htm  Is this what you were wanting to know?

Comment: The link you have provided does not seem to mention `FamilyName`. However [I found it here](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/ec272d75-d6d5-db03-57bd-12415ca6abf5.htm) and it seems to be a read-only property. Can you find out if this property is meant to be written to?

Comment: Thanks again, I found this link and tried to convert to python, but no luck.  I'm still learning and feel bad for asking all the questions!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414625/revit-family-rename-in-a-project

Comment: Don't feel bad for good questions. Make sure your posts here are clear, well-formatted and evidence your prior effort, and you will find readers (of all levels) appreciate them.

Comment: It's not easy working with niche APIs as a beginner - plenty of readers can help you with APIs, but very few can help you with this one in particular. Hopefully some general advice will do the trick!

Comment: thanks one last time halfer.  You made me think and look back at things and I found my error.  It's posted for anyone else who makes rookie mistakes.  Giving up is not part of my nature, but it does cause a lack of sleep!

Comment: Lovely. Would you post that as an answer? There is a button that says "Answer your own question". Doing it that way means you can click the tick mark, and "self-accept". This takes it out of the unanswered questions list. You can then roll the question back using the controls [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61505093/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

```
t = Transaction(doc, 'loadfamily')
t.Start()

#Rename Family Type

Elements = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(FamilySymbol).WhereElementIsElementType()
for m in Elements:
    try:
        contains = "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (PIN07)"
        if m.FamilyName.startswith((contains)):
            m.Name = contains + "Append"
    except:
        print "Type name not changed"

#Rename Family
Elements = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family)

for m in Elements:
    try:
        contains = "VA Titleblock Consultant Logo (PIN07)"
        if m.Name.startswith((contains)):
            m.Name = "VA Im Slow"
    except:
        print "what an idiot, I finally got it"

t.Commit()
```

Comment: Great, thanks for posting it. If you can, please add an introduction for future readers. What part of this solved it? What did you change? etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the family is hard-coded to match the family definition `RFA` filename. At least, that is what Revit always expects. Obviously, once the family has been loaded into a project and the `RFA` file is no longer present, you may be able to change it. I would be pretty careful in doing so, though...